# laravel queue not working like it did before

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

Hello i was working with mailable and using queue but when i used `php artisan queue:listen` and send a mail it did not work like it was supposed to do, i did get the email on mailtrap, but there was no message in my console. I tried sending the mail first and then use my command but it worked without my command. and it does not take a while because its sending immediately here is my code

controller.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\testmail;

class Controller extends Controller{
    public function email($email, Request $request){
        $emailuser = $request->input('email');
        $message = $request->input('bericht');
        mail::to($email)->queue(new testmail($emailuser, $message));
    }
}
```

testmail.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class testmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $emailuser;
    public $message;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($emailuser, $message)
    {
        $this->emailuser = $emailuser;
        $this->message = $message;

    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('email.mail');
    }
}
```

mail.blade.php

```
@component('mail::message')
{{ $emailuser }}
{{ $message }}


Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

does anyone know how to fixs this because i need it to have a delay for my application

Answer (score -2):

Use a job instead of Maillable and in that job in handle function write down the code to send the email in that job
 for i.e-:

```
$job = (new SendWelcomeEmail($activation->code,$user))->onQueue('default');
```

and the job file SendwelcomeEmail would like following-:

```
<?php

  namespace App\Jobs;

  use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
  use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
  use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
  use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
  use App\Jobs\Job;
  use Mail;


class SendWelcomeEmail extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
  use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected $activation_code;
protected $user;
public function __construct($activation_code,$user)
{

    $this->activation_code=$activation_code;
    $this->user=$user;

}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    try{
    $user=$this->user;
    Mail::send('emails.user.register', ['activation_code' => $this->activation_code,'user'=>$this->user], function ($m) use ($user) {
                    $m->to($user->email,$user->first_name." ".$user->last_name)
                        ->subject(trans('emails.USER_REGISTER_SUBJECT',['project'=>trans('project.project_name')]));
                });
        \Log::useDailyFiles(storage_path().'/logs/user-registration/success/'.date('Y-m-d').'.log');
        \Log::info('Welcome Email Send to-:'.$user->email);
    }catch(Exception $ex){
        \Log::useDailyFiles(storage_path().'/logs/user-registration/error/'.date('Y-m-d').'.log');
        \Log::error($ex->getMessage());
        \Log::error("Line Number->".$ex->getLine());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is not answering OP's question but rather smells like workaround w/o bothering what the real culprit.

Comment: Thats not a work arround that is the implementation of Jobs and in this way it is very easy to debug and trace, because from laravel 5.2 onwards you can not use Maill::queue() directly without a maillable class or job